# sort a list of strings and numbers by number

Tags: python

Help please :

```
myliste = ['Bullet train\t5018\n', 'Prey\t508\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n', 'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n', 'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Darling\t2008\n', 'Alina of Cuba\t678\n', 'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n', 'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n', 'Luck\t3148\n', 'Sita Ramam\t4498\n', 'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n', 'Wedding Season\t2490\n', 'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n', 'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Hero Mode\t245\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n', 'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'Mission Eagle\t998\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745']
```

I want to sort this list according to the number, from the highest number to the lowest without changing the elements of my list, I have tried this :

```
def sort_films(LF):
        a = i.index('\t')
        b = i.index('\n')
        c = i[a+2:b]
        return(c)

LF.sort(key=sort_films,reverse=True)
```

the result I have is :

```
['Wedding Season\t2490\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n', 'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Sita Ramam\t4498\n', 'Prey\t508\n', 'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n', 'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Mission Eagle\t998\n', 'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n', 'Luck\t3148\n', 'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n', 'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n', 'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Hero Mode\t245\n', 'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n', 'Darling\t2008\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Bullet train\t5018\n', 'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n', 'Alina of Cuba\t678\n']
```

I don't know what to do please if you have a solution

Comment: It seems that I ordered well for the first values but then I have later on the list bigger values that had been forgotten and not ordered well.

Comment: add `print(sort_films(myliste[0]))` to your program and see what it prints

Comment: Last item `'Doblemente Embarazada\t745'` has no `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work as expected:

```
LF = ['Bullet train\t5018\n', 'Prey\t508\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n', 'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n', 'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Darling\t2008\n', 'Alina of Cuba\t678\n', 'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n', 'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n', 'Luck\t3148\n', 'Sita Ramam\t4498\n', 'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n', 'Wedding Season\t2490\n', 'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n', 'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Hero Mode\t245\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n', 'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'Mission Eagle\t998\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745\n']

def sort_films(i):
        a = i.index('\t')
        try:
            b = i.index('\n')
        except:
            b = len(i)
        c = int(i[a+1:b]) # +1 instead of +2 as first digit must not be skipped
        return(c)

LF.sort(key=sort_films,reverse=True)
print(LF)
```

Output:

```
['Bullet train\t5018\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Sita Ramam\t4498\n', 'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n', 'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n', 'Luck\t3148\n', 'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Wedding Season\t2490\n', 'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n', 'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Darling\t2008\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n', 'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n', 'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n', 'Mission Eagle\t998\n', 'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n', 'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745', 'Alina of Cuba\t678\n', 'Prey\t508\n', 'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Hero Mode\t245\n']
```

Comment: Yes it works but we have the problem of the last one which doesn't have a "\n" at the end so it has not been ordered and placed at the end where it should not be as it is a higher value than the previous ones, how can i solve that ? thank you a lot btw

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex and a lambda function to provide the key for sort. `\d+` will find strings of at least one number in each list item. To avoid the case of a number in the title, the sort is done on the last number found in the list item.

```
import re
sorted_myliste =  sorted(myliste, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[-1]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach with `filter` + `str.isdigit`,

```
sorted(myliste, key=lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['Bullet train\t5018\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Sita Ramam\t4498\n', 'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n', 'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n', 'Luck\t3148\n', 'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Wedding Season\t2490\n', 'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n', 'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Darling\t2008\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n', 'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n', 'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n', 'Mission Eagle\t998\n', 'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n', 'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745', 'Alina of Cuba\t678\n', 'Prey\t508\n', 'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Hero Mode\t245\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using `numpy` and `re`, you can convert to numpy array and then use `re` to extract the numbers. Then you can sort the array with `argsort`.

```
import re
import numpy as np


def sort_films(LF, reverse=False):
    numbers = np.array([re.findall(r'\d+', s) for s in myliste]).flatten().astype(int)
    if reverse==False:
        return list(np.array(myliste)[np.argsort(numbers)])
    else:
        return list(np.array(myliste)[np.argsort(numbers)][::-1])
```

Then `sort_films(myliste)` outputs:

```
['Hero Mode\t245\n', 'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Prey\t508\n',
   'Alina of Cuba\t678\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745',
   'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n',
   'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n',
   'Mission Eagle\t998\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n',
   'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n',
   'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n', 'Darling\t2008\n',
   'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n',
   'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Wedding Season\t2490\n',
   'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Luck\t3148\n',
   'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n', 'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n',
   'Sita Ramam\t4498\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Bullet train\t5018\n']
```

and `sort_films(myliste, reverse=True)` gives

```
['Bullet train\t5018\n', 'Carter\t5004\n', 'Sita Ramam\t4498\n',
   'Lâ€™annÃ©e du requin\t4398\n', 'Les Promesses dâ€™Hasan\t3598\n',
   'Luck\t3148\n', 'MÃ©nestrel\t3065\n', 'Wedding Season\t2490\n',
   'Poikkal Kudhirai\t2248\n', 'Des feux dans la nuit\t2144\n',
   'The Bikeriders\t2134\n', 'Darling\t2008\n', 'Treize vies\t1978\n',
   'En dÃ©calage\t1789\n', 'Night Raiders\t1312\n',
   'The Last Son\t1245\n', 'Embuscade\t1038\n',
   'Mission Eagle\t998\n',
   'Le Destin des Tortues Ninja, le Film\t845\n',
   'Amants Super-hÃ©roÃ¯ques\t837\n', 'Doblemente Embarazada\t745',
   'Alina of Cuba\t678\n', 'Prey\t508\n',
   'La Vie en plus grand\t489\n', 'Hero Mode\t245\n']
```